# Tensorflow hangs. What are some things I can do to debug the issue

Tags: tensorflow

Ive written a seq2seq network, using the facebook fastText vectors for my embeddings. I'm running into an issue where the model will run and train fine maybe 40% of the time and then randomly hangs at the start of training the other 60% of the time.

Some things I have considered are any tweak to my parameters may be causing a bottleneck, because of how large the emebeddings are, 300x100000 and sequence length on average of 10 units. That said using nvidia-smi I can see its not a computational bottle neck as the GPU only shows somewhere between 9-20% usage at a given time. Similarly the network does do some pool resizing, but never have I hit an OOM on the runs where my model successfully trains. I'm using a scheduled train helper for my training decoder and a beam search decoder for my prediction decoder.

It's becoming a bit of a crapshoot because every time I restart the training after making a tweak I risk spending more time killing the process and re running then actually seeing the experiment play out. Im on an EC2 p2xlarge instance with a single K80 at 12gib vram.

In addition is there any way to quickly check that the hang is indeed a hang and that tensorflow is not actually just hard at work crunching numbers for me? I have hooks setup to print at intervals of 2000 steps at the moment, however it doesn't look like even one step has been taken. Is there something that would show me more granularly that a certain opnode is being executed.

I've tried tfdbg as well I don't think it compatible with the contrib.estimator.estimator that I'm using because it crashes on the invoke_stepper after a few steps to weird errors that from the stack trace don't seem to be related to my code.

Comment: One of the most common "hanging" issues is with starved queues. Are you feeding data into a queue? If so fire up another thread and print out the size of that queue every second or so and see if you're starting the queue.

Comment: You could attach with gdb or strace to see where it's hanging. If it's hanging inside session.run call you can add tf.Print statements to figure out which op it's hanging on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case after attaching gdb and looking at the threads it looked like things were locking. I searched for an issue on tensorflow's github related to that and it turns out there was a massive thread on a potential livelocking issue that looked similar to mine. At the end of that thread another related issue was linked to with summary writers failing to close threads and spawning an unmanageable number of threads.

I was using a higher level logging mechanism from tf.train "tf.train.LoggingTensorHook" and as it turns out this doesn't use the summary writers, so the leap I made was this function for some reason was not playing nice with tensorflow's internal threading and locking everything up in similar fashion. Since removing the logging hook I have had 0 hangs and run over 20 runs to successful completion as well as a few longer runs with over 100000's of steps.